# How to count different arrays line numbers from reading a file

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing a school assignment. It requires me to read names and income from a file and put everyone that is in the same family together to calculate the family's tax. 
I have already put people into different arrays, but I am having a hard time to count how many family members that each family has.

The file that I am reading from looks like this:

> Jones Ralph 39765.45
>
> Jones Mary 18532.00
>
> Jones Frank 0.00
>
> Hansen John 63321.00
>
> Hansen Linda 8765.00
>
> Murphy Jeff 53786.75
>
> Murphy Nina 65432.00
>
> Murphy Ellen 0.00
>
> Murphy David 0.00
>
> Simon Mike 7654.00
>
> Simon Janet 44762.00
>
> Simon Tom 0.00

I have tried to insert count++ into several places but none of them would give me the correct answer. Please help me here.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class caltax
{
public static void main (String[] args) 
{    

// 1. Define two arrays
String[] families = null;
double[] taxes = null;

// 2. Read file:
 try 
  {
  Scanner infile = new Scanner (new FileInputStream("family.dat"));

while (infile.hasNextLine()) 
{
    String personLastName = infile.next();

    //skip the first name 
    infile.next();

    double personTax = infile.nextDouble();

    // add person data
    if (null == families) 
    {
        // create array for
        families = new String[] { personLastName };
        taxes = new double[] { personTax };
    } 
    else 
    {
        boolean familyExists = false;

        // check existing families
        for (int i = 0; i < families.length; i++) 
        {
            if (personLastName.equals(families[i])) 
            {
                // add personTax to family owed taxes
              taxes[i] += personTax;  

                familyExists = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!familyExists) 
        {
            // Extend arrays to put new family
            // create temp arrays with size+1

            String[] tmpFamilies = new String[families.length + 1];
            double[] tmpTaxes = new double[taxes.length + 1];


            System.arraycopy(families, 0, tmpFamilies, 0, families.length);
            System.arraycopy(taxes, 0, tmpTaxes, 0, taxes.length);

            // set new last elements data
            tmpFamilies[tmpFamilies.length - 1] = personLastName;

            tmpTaxes[tmpTaxes.length - 1] = personTax;

            // replace families and taxes with newly created tmp arrays
            families = tmpFamilies;
            taxes = tmpTaxes;
        }
    }//else

}// while


infile.close();
 }//try

 catch(Exception e) 
{
System.out.println(e.toString());
}//catch block 

// Print results

for (int i=0;i < families.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("family " + families[i] + " owes $" + taxes[i]);

}
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html ?

Comment: see, the thing is my professor never taught us MAP method, so I assume that she doesn't want us to use map

Comment: Why not use another array to keep track of the count for each family?

Comment: @DavidChoweller where to add it? under the first if?

Comment: You have to define it where you define the other arrays, and you have to resize it when you resize the other arrays.  You have to increment the count at the index associated with a particular family when you encounter the last name of that family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add another array

```
...
int []familyCount = null
if (null == families) 
{
    // create array for
    families = new String[] { personLastName };
    taxes = new double[] { personTax };
    familyCount = new int[] {1};

} 
else 
{
    boolean familyExists = false;

    // check existing families
    for (int i = 0; i < families.length; i++) 
    {
        if (personLastName.equals(families[i])) 
        {
            // add personTax to family owed taxes
          taxes[i] += personTax;  

          familyCount[i] ++;

            familyExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!familyExists) 
    {
        // Extend arrays to put new family
        // create temp arrays with size+1

        String[] tmpFamilies = new String[families.length + 1];
        double[] tmpTaxes = new double[taxes.length + 1];
        int[] tmpFamilyCount = new int[familyCount.length+1];


        ...
        System.arraycopy(familyCount, 0, tmpFamilyCount, 0, familyCount.length);

        // set new last elements data 
        ...
        tmpFamilyCount[tmpFamilyCount.length-1] = 1;

        // replace families and taxes with newly created tmp arrays 
        ...
        familyCount = tmpFamilyCount;
    }
}//else
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1. Define two arrays
...
HashMap<String,Integer> familyMember=null;

    if (null == families) 
    {
        ...
        familyMember = new HashMap();
        familyMember.put(personLastName, new Integer(1));        
    } else {

      ....
       for (int i = 0; i < families.length; i++) 
        {
            if (personLastName.equals(families[i])) 
            {

              int totalPerson = familyMember.get(personLastName).intValue();   
              familyMember.put(personLastName, new Integer(totalPerson));
                .....
            }
        }

       if (!familyExists) 
        {
              ....
              familyMember.put(personLastName, new Integer(1));
        }
    }

  // Print Results

  for (String key : familyMember.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("family " + key + " has " + familyMember.get(key).toString() + " person");
  }
```

**UPDATE - Without HashMap**

With useful **[split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)** method

```
// 1. Define two arrays
...
String[] familyMember=null;

    if (null == families) 
    {
        ...
        familyMember = new String[]{personLastName +"-1"};        
    } else {

      ....
       for (int i = 0; i < families.length; i++) 
        {
            if (personLastName.equals(families[i])) 
            {

              int totalPerson = Integer.parseInt(familyMember[i].split("-")[1]);   
              familyMember[i] = families[i]+"-"+String.valueOf(totalPerson+1);
                .....
            }
        }

       if (!familyExists) 
        {
              ....
              String[] tmpFamilyMember = new String[familyMember.length + 1];
             System.arraycopy(familyMember, 0, tmpFamilyMember, 0, familyMember.length);

              tmpFamilyMember[tmpFamilyMember.length - 1] = personLastName+"-1";

           /* **UPDATE** */
           familyMember =  tmpFamilyMember;

        }
    }

  // Print Results

  for (String fam : familyMember) {
    String[] familyWithCount = fam.split("-");
    System.out.println("family " + familyWithCount[0] + " has " + familyWithCount[1] + " person");
  }
```

---

Result:

family Jones owes $58297.45

family Hansen owes $72086.0

family Murphy owes $119218.75

family Simon owes $52416.0

family Jones has 3 person

family Hansen has 2 person

family Murphy has 4 person

family Simon has 3 person

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. But my professor never taught us MAP method, so is there any other ways to solve this?

Comment: It only gives me the first family's count

Comment: I will test it now

Comment: Ok I just forget to assign tempFamilyMember to familyMember